# Cannot boot into windows after deleting linux

Tags: boot, multi-boot, grub, mbr

A little over a year ago I installed both Linux and Windows on my machine (GPT partition table, dual boot with grub loader).

Since I needed some space on my hard drive and considering I wasn't using Linux that much I decided to delete it by booting from Windows, opening the disk management program, deleting all partitions without a label and resizing my primary C: partition to incorporate those to the right of it (unfortunately this left two small partitions to the right of it, which I deleted using diskpart).

Then I tried fixing the MBR by booting from a repair disc, opening a prompt and launching: bootrec /fixmbr which seemed to work fine and gave no errors. After doing this unfortunately i can't boot into Windows anymore. So booting from a live Linux distro, now I'm in this situation:

[image]

I'll appreciate any help.

Comment: The now unallocated ~550MB looks like it might have been an ESP (EFI System Partition). Rule of thumb: Do not touch ESP. Managing a dual boot in UEFI mode is as easy as it can be. If removing one of the OSes simply go to UEFI settings and change the boot order to the other one. Left over EFI entries can be deleted with tools from within the OS (Windows or Ubuntu) or from UEFI settings. Or just left there because they don't interfere with anything else.

Answer (score 0):

> A little over a year ago i installed both linux and windows on my
>   machine (**gpt partition table**, dual boot with grub loader).

Is looks like you are using GPT, which implies uEFI not BIOS/MBR, so repairing MBR will not help. You should try [Windows Startup Repair](https://www.boyans.net/RepairWindows/repair-windows-boot.html). It should fix it.

> deleting all partitions **without a label** and resizing my primary...

BTW, that partitions was probably ESP (EFI System Partition) with GRUB and Windows Boot Manager.

Answer (score -1):

Repairing munged dual boot issues can end up in a run around of advice from the LINUX vs Windows community.

After destroying my own system with a removed dual boot LINUX bootup, I also failed to restore the partition using Windows Repair and resorted to a LIVE Linux boot repair from Sourceforge:

https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair-cd/home/Home/

It was about 500mb and took longer to burn to a USB using [Rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie/) than the quick amount of time it spent fixing my startup issues by repairing the Windows boot function after I roasted it.[image]

It just works and is 500MB since the author includes a LINUX XServer for the stripped GUI along with other disk management and system utilities, but the boot repair function is practically automatic and works for me and my friends when problems like yours arise.