# Will my computer boot after deleting boot partition in dual boot?

Tags: linux, windows, partitioning, multi-boot, bootloader

I have installed linux Mint beside windows as dual boot OS.

My computer is now booting by GRUB bootloader.

Now i don't want linux anymore.

My partition table is :-

1. 549 MB -> System Reserved (Windows bootloader)
2. 112 GB -> C Drive
3. 1 GB -> /boot
4. 8 GB -> swap area
5. 116 GB -> /root

If i delete 3,4 and 5 partition.

Will my computer boot correctly with windows bootloader?

I just want to know before breaking anything.

Comment: Do you still have the BIOS? It should mention something about Windows or HDD in the boot section. Also, if you plan on nuking the linux partition, DO NOT delete partitions with no names. https://superuser.com/questions/1272499/cannot-boot-into-windows-after-deleting-linux?rq=1

Comment: Partition 1 house the Windows boot files, 3, 4, & 5 are Linux only. Also, unless two of those are Extended partitions (required if BIOS, as BIOS only supports 4 Logical partitions), if you have a UEFI motherboard, Windows should be re-installed with CSM mode off.

Comment: I have only 5 partition in my ssd. 
If i delete 3,4,5 and extend C drive.
Will it boot from partition 1 (windows bootloader) ?
Currently my computer is booting from GRUB bootloader, (Partition 3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it would not boot. GRUB would be unable to find its files and you'll see the infamous GRUB's black screen.

You can just restore the Windows bootloader, and then simply delete the Linux partitions.

If your system is on UEFI, then in UEFI firmware settings (accessible by pressing the function keys like `F10` on boot) you can make Windows bootloader the priority, and then delete GRUB entry. You would be able to hop in to Windows bootloader directly. If GRUB files still persist in EFI partition, you could delete that.

For MBR systems, just "fix"/restore MBR from Windows bootable USBs.

Here is a question containing answers for both the cases:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/429610/uninstall-grub-and-use-windows-bootloader

Comment: Didn't realize with UEFI, you can select between the Windows bootloader and GRUB. That's pretty neat since you don't need to do the windows bootable USBs to run bootrec/bootsect.